# audio control in FF bleeps in and out, OGG and .htaccess already modified

Tags: .htaccess, audio, controls, wav, ogg

The audio controller bleeps in and disappears upon page refresh in Firefox browser. I have modified my .htaccess to

```
AddType audio/ogg ogg
AddType audio/ogg oga
AddType audio/wav wav
AddType audio/mpeg mp3
AddType audio/mp4 mp4
AddType audio/mp4 mpa
```

with and without the .'s and it is the unresolved. My coding is:

```
<audio controls style="width:70px">
<source src="Sound/buoyharborbell.wav" type="audio/wav"></source>
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

ogg and mp3 works. If anyone has been able to get this working with firefox using a wav file please update it here.